# What's the cause for these 2 hardware faults?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, diagnostic, windows-error-reporting, minidumps

I've got 2 hardware faults located inside `Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance\Problem Reports`, and I'm hoping someone here could help shine some light on what's possibly causing them. They are old logs, dating back in the summer (3-4 months ago)

I've hooked an audio system to my laptop that always stays plugged in via USB. (2.0 in a 3.1 type-C connector).

Here are the two dumps in question:

```
Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   1000015e
Parameter 1:    25
Parameter 2:    23
Parameter 3:    ffffbf8b0fa24b38
Parameter 4:    e040101
OS version: 10_0_17763
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.17763.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
```

And the second one:

```
Description
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   144
Parameter 1:    3003
Parameter 2:    ffff8102100825c0
Parameter 3:    40010002
Parameter 4:    0
OS version: 10_0_17763
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.17763.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*PS: I'm not sure what tags I need to use here. If someone could help out. Thank you too!*

**Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434)** *taken from dxdiag tool.*

Comment: It appears you are running an extremely out of date installation of 1809.  I would install any and all available 1809 updates.  I based this on the fact the version being reported is `10.0.17763.2` which was released over 15 months ago.

Comment: @Ramhound huh? I've enabled auto-updates. I just ran it again, and it reports that I'm up to date? What does that mean? These crash reports happened 4 months ago. Are they both tied with that problem? I just wanted to get some insight as to why they happened. Thank you!
EDIT: The only thing that I remember tweaking for the updates, was feature updates. There are major problems on the latest 1903 with my nvidia graphics card. Until it's more stable, I'll be sticking to 1809.

Comment: I have seen these errors. Try updating BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers.  Do a full reset of Edge (Start, Settings, Apps, scroll down for Microsoft Edge, Advanced, and then both Repair and Reset).  Close out, restart and test.

Comment: @John thank you. I've done the Edge stuff. Everything else is up to date (just checked). I never use Edge, but might as well do it, right?

Comment: Try resetting Edge to see. I have see Edge interaction cause this issue. Newer Windows builds seem to have solved it.

Comment: Its a USB 3 bugcheck "A USB device failed enumeration.">>>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x144--bugcode-usb3-driver

Comment: Update your USB 3.0 driver

Comment: @Moab I've installed all drivers provided by Acer. My chipset is intel. Could you explain from where I can update it?

Comment: You might try updating it using device manager, right click on the usb 3.0 host controller and select update>search automatically, windows update will attempt to find a newer driver

Comment: @Moab Thank you. That's what my hunch said as well. It's USB3.1 eXtensible host controller - 1.10 (Microsoft). It appears to be up to date. The fact that the crashes happened 3 months ago might have fixed the isssue. Or maybe I fixed it with some other tweaks. Basically I allowed windows before to boot up all my programs before I authenticated myself. Maybe that played a bad role on the USB 3.1 driver, tied with my audio station. Thank you!